# getting the COUNT of unique values on django queryset with for loop

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

newbie here on django and django-rest-framework. May I ask if it is possible to get the COUNT of the unique values on a for loop? I have encountered this use case where I need to get the the COUNT of all unique values on a for loop querysets. The implementation was to loop within the querysets and put on the list all the unique objects and return the len() of it. The problem with this implementation was it causes multiple queries on the DB base on django-debug-toolbar. Please see code below for reference. Is there another way to implement this? Thank you in advance.

```
activity_list = []

classes = Class.objects.all()

for class in classes:
    student_activities = class.studentactivity_set.all()

    for activity in student_activities:
        if activity not in activity_list:
            activity_list.append(activity)

return len(activity_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to turn it into a set and then use `len()` function on the set. You can also add elements directly to the set, that should save you from doing any extra comparisons.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
>>> len(lst)
5
>>> st = set(lst)
>>> len(st)
4
>>> st.add(5)
>>> len(st)
5
>>> st.add(5)
>>> len(st)
5
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but is there another way where we can avoid for loop?

Comment: This gets rid of the inner for loop. Do you want to get rid of the of the outer for loop as well?

Comment: How this removes the inner for loop? Pardon me as I am a newbie. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the power of Django ORM:

```
activity_count = (StudentActivity.objects
  .exclude(related_class=None) # exclude not linked activities
  .count() # count unique items
)
```

I have not tested this code, please do it yourself.

Comment: Hi, will this provide activity_count per class? This is why I for loop it so I can get every activity per class.

Comment: I oriented on your code example. You get the count of StudentActivity instances, which related at least with one Class instance. Is it right? Or you need another behavior?
If two or more activities related to the class, there are a few different activity items. By which attribute you want to identify them as duplicates?
It would be nice if you provide your model classes.

Comment: Well, I need to get the count of unique activities per class on every student. This is needed since I am validating all graded activities versus the activities which is not yet graded. Although I am not putting the filter() as a just want to have a simple sample of the code.

Comment: Sample if i print a querset you got queryset<[1, 2, 3] > on the first class, then on the second class I got the queryset<[3, 4]>, I need to get unique ids 1,2,3,4 since those activity means graded already and the first class was not graded on activity ids 4 while the second class was not graded for activity ids 1 and 2